# PDO Postgres Invalid error

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm getting this problem when connecting to a database. I'm trying to write a query containing sub-queries to run on Postgres, usind PDO. Unfortunately I get an "Invalid parameter number: :sensor"

```
    $statement="select  di_timestamp, di_item_value
from data_item
where
fk_fc_id=(select fc_id 
        from field_column
        where 
        fc_description is like ':sensor'
        and
        fk_mds_id=( select mds_id 
                    from monitored_data_set
                    where fk_pa_id=(select pa_id 
                        from pilot_ambient 
                        where   
                        pa_ambient_name ilike ':room'
                        and 
                        fk_sp_id=(
                            select sp_id 
                            from School_Pilot 
                            where sp_description ilike '%:name%'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )";
$query = $databaseConn->prepare($statement);

$query->execute(array(':sensor'=>'Room Temperature',':room'=>'rm1',':name' => 'school1'));
```

I think my problem is due to the escaping of the ' characters surrounding the :(item). I've tried using \ but that then creates a syntax error. I presume there's a convention I'm unaware of for PHP to successfully substitute the string and then it not cause an error in Postgres.

Thanks for looking at this,
James

Comment: use `in` instead of `=` also this many sub queries will kill your db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the single quotes surrounding the name of the parameters, something like this:

From => `':sensor'` To => `:sensor`

In this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) you will find an explanation.

Comment: If you mean in the query, it doesn't work, I get this error,Exception called.
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 19:         where sp_description ilike %$3%

Comment: Try to remove the % sighs from the SQL statements and put them in the arguments, i.e. `':name' => '%school1%'));`

Comment: Ah, the combination of moving the % signs into the variable and unquoting in the query worked.